# PHP - How can I replace after the 2nd occurrence of a tab

Tags: php, regexp-replace

I have a string like this, with several tabs in it.  I need to replace a single digit, it will always be the digit after the 2nd tab.  The numbers before that could be different lengths, so I can't simply replace after 10 digits or something like that.  It has to be after the 2nd tab.   the new string will be exactly the same except for that one digit.  example...

`222[TAB]55555[TAB]9[TAB]hello[TAB]byebye[TAB]444`

change to

`222[TAB]55555[TAB]2[TAB]hello[TAB]byebye[TAB]444`

Comment: `explode("\t", $string};` or `str_getcsv($string, "\t");`

Comment: If you want to use regex have you tried anything with it yet?

Comment: Isn't it a TSV format?

Comment: I'm not good with regex, but I would like to use that I think.  I think I see what Sammitch is saying. split up the string by tabs, replace, then rebuild the string?    I rather use regex if possible.  Any ideas?

Comment: @RoboRobok technically the C in CSV stands for "character" and the delimiter can be anything. Comma, tab, hash...

Comment: @Sammitch I've never heard of this revelation. I googled and found such definition on IBM's website. All others claim that C stands for comma. TSV is a thing too, there's even a .tsv file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$input = "222\t55555\t9\thello\tbyebye\t444";

$parts = explode("\t", $input);
$parts[2] = 2;
$output = implode("\t", $parts);

var_dump($output);
```

Or:

```php
$input = "222\t55555\t9\thello\tbyebye\t444";

$parts = str_getcsv($input, "\t");
$parts[2] = 2;
$output = implode("\t", $parts);

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
string(28) "222 55555   2   hello   byebye  444"
```

`str_getcsv()` being more useful if your data includes encapsulated strings, line breaks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the integer value after the second occurring tab, match the first occuring tab, then one or more non-tab characterss, then the second tab, then forget all of those matched characters with `\K`, then match the one or more digit number.  Replace the matched number with the new desired value.  Limit the number of replacements to one.

This is more direct than exploding or parsing the entire string just to change one value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eOl9c))

```
$string = "222\t55555\t9\thello\tbyebye\t444";
$newInt = 2;
var_export(
    preg_replace("/\t[^\t]+\t\K\d+/", $newInt, $string, 1)
);
```

Comment: Related: [How do I remove texts after the second comma in php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74215217/2943403) and [PHP extract string after second comma](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50700223/2943403)